# Are there/were there use cases of serialized Properties where keys and values were not strings?

Tags: java, history, properties-file

The [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class in Java is a historical artifact; nowadays, it has been retrofitted to obey the `Map` interface, but since this class predates `Map` itself, therefore the collections API and generics, it implements `Map<Object, Object>`.

You can however use a `Properties` instance to either load from a given resource, or write to a given resource.

My question is as follows, and note that I haven't had a look at the source code of this class: has there ever been any use case of a "serializable" `Properties` instance where either keys or values are *not* `String`s? By "serializable", I mean an instance which can be stored to a file and loaded from that same file.

Comment: any use case in the whole history of anyone who has ever used java?

Comment: @jtahlborn basically, yes; of course, I don't really expect a "yes" answer to that!

Comment: i guess i don't understand?  are you asking people to write in and say if they've ever used it that way in their code?

Comment: @jtahlborn or witnessed someone using `Properties` this way. I know I haven't, but then I have only been using Java since 1 year after Java 5 was born

Comment: The answer is yes. You might take a look at using the Apache Commons [`PropertiesConfiguration`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch interesting... Having had a cursory read of the link you provide, it appears that this class allows to basically "map" values to POJOs or primitive types; however, the underlying property file is still text, right?

Comment: @fge It might be EBCDIC on an AS/400. What exactly are you asking? A binary format? Of what?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch basically, any use case where keys and/or values were not bona fide Java `String`s. As to EBCDIC, this is a character coding anyway, so this basically counts as text ultimately ;)